# Multiple dependencies on a server/client java program makefile

Tags: java, makefile, client-server

I am trying to write a makefile for a multithreaded java client/server chat program. However; I am getting an error in my terminal as shown below:

make: Nothing to be done for `default'.

Here is my makefile (Note that client_thread.class is a class under Server.java)

```
JCC = javac

J = java

JFLAGS = -g -Xlint

default: Server.class Client.class

Server.class: Server.java
    $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) Server.java 


Client.class: Client.java
    $(JCC) $(JFLAGS) Client.java

clean:
    rm -f *.class
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use a more modern Java build system like Gradle or Maven?  Also the error message means it can't find `client_thread.java` and is trying to figure out how to make it.

Comment: I can't use Gradle or Mavern. client_thread.java is a subclass of Server.java and I don't know how to include it in my makefile.

Comment: Is it a separate file? If by "subclass" you mean nested class within `Server`, then you don't need to mention it in the makefile at all.  It will be compiled when `Server` is compiled.

Comment: Yes sorry it is a subclass and when I delete client_thread.java from the makefile, it says nothing to be done for default.

Comment: Please learn to use the correct terminology.  "subclass" has a very specific meaning, and does NOT mean "nested class".  The reason it says "nothing to be done" is because you have already compiled the `Server` and `Client` classes.  The timestamps on the `.class` files are later than the corresponding `.java` files so there really is nothing to be done.

Comment: Thank you very much! I fixed it by deleting everything related to the nested class.